Complex Ligatures in CMU Serif
Currently my LaTeX font (CMU Serif) only gives me the common ligatures (ie: fi, ff, fl, ffi, and ffl).
But I want the discretionary ligatures to appear in my file (ie: fb, fj, st, ct, tt, Th, and many others).
I have tried \setmainfont[Ligatures  = Discretionary]{CMU Serif} with package fontspec, but it doesn't seem working.
Any ideas?
If possible, please give me the code with your answer. Thanks.

The font doesn’t have the dlig feature. You could add the feature if the font had the glyphs, but I don’t see them.

Fonts aren't required to have any ligature you'd like to.
New Computer Modern Roman has some more than CMU Serif.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{NewCM10}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}
]

\begin{document}

ff fi fl ffi ffl

fb fj st ct tt Th

\end{document}


You need to check with a particular font documentation to see what ligatures, either common or discretionary, it has.
Without Discretionary the same input gives

which I'd prefer, because the font is based, like Knuth's, on Monotype Modern, which was born long after those ligatures fell out of fashion.
